# Hive external table on data containing newline

Tags: hadoop, hive, newline

I have a few txt files on which I want to create an external table. 
Unfortunately, the content of the files also contains the string "\n" from time to time. It seems that Hive interprets this as a newline, even though it's not a newline in the original file and is just part of the text. 
Can I catch this problem in Hive without having to alter the original txt files?

Answer (score 0):

You can put any other delimiter at end of each line(other than \n and your field separator).And than can register that delimiter in table properties.
Eg: Let's say I have record like this

1,2,3,aniit\n,4\n

In this record aniit\n is a string and \n is string.So hive makes it two record.To avoid this ,you can add any other delimiter at end.Like

1,2,3,aniit\n,4\n||

Here '||' is Line delimiter and my create table will look like :

```
    create external table if not exists table1
    (
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    col4 string,
    col5 string
    )
    row format delimited fields terminated by ','
    lines terminated by '||'
    stored as textfile
    location '/tmp/table1';
```

Comment: considering it a big data system with the amount of data we usually we have, how do you propose we change just the line delimiter and not the newline character in-between the data?

Comment: there are unix commands to add delimiters at end of each line.copy data to unix ,then edit it and copy back to hdfs .

Comment: not sure, if this could be feasible considering the data volume. Do you think there's any other way out ? Well, one thing is if they're using sqoop to get data then we can use another delimiter. Not sure, if we have another way out for humongous data sets except for MapReduce.